# State var nil in SwiftUI with async await (CloudKit)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, async-await, cloudkit

I haven't done much with the changes to SwiftUI concurrency with async await but I have gone through all the documentation and I really don't get what's going on here:

I try to share my CloudKit database with other users, I implemented basically 1:1 what Apple is showing here in the sample code
https://github.com/apple/sample-cloudkit-sharing/blob/main/Sharing/Views/ContentView.swift
https://github.com/apple/sample-cloudkit-sharing/blob/main/Sharing/Views/CloudSharingView.swift

this is my code

```
Button("share") {
    Task {
            try await shareObjects()
    }
}
.sheet(isPresented: $isShowingShareView) {
    shareView()
}


@State private var activeShare: CKShare?
@State private var activeContainer: CKContainer?

func shareObjects() async throws {
    
    var objects = Array(viewContext.registeredObjects)
    do {
        let (something, share, container) = try await PersistenceController.shared.container.share(objects, to: nil)
        activeShare = share
        activeContainer = container // here its not nil
        isShowingShareView = true
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
    
}

private func shareView() -> CloudSharingView? {
    guard let share = activeShare, let container = activeContainer else {
        print("its nil") // here share and container are nil
        return nil
    }

    return CloudSharingView(container: container, share: share)
}
```

The share view should come up in the sheet, but it just comes up empty because share and container are nil when `shareView()` is called (where it prints its nil). When setting breakpoints I see there is data in there - then not anymore, I suspect some kind of issue where this view just knows nothing about my data but why?
I also added @MainActor for the methods just to make sure its really on the main thread, but it is. The share action does work, I can see it in CloudKit Dashboard

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: try  using `.sheet(item:ondismiss:content:)`, see:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/sheet(item:ondismiss:content:)  There are a lot of similar posts/answers on this in SO.

Comment: State doesn’t work with class instances…

Comment: Hey thank you both, yes I tried using the item: way but forgot to mention it, it doesn't work either, crashes the App outright because its nil again - it crashes then on @ main  @workingdogsupportUkraine

Comment: The Views are just structs, there is no class @cora

Comment: SwiftUI triggers a recompute of the body `valueWillChange`, as a dirty fix try `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now + 1) { self.isShowingShareView = true }` see if it fixes the issue. If yes then refactor your code to use an @StateObject and a custom model to hold your `activeContainer` and `activeShare`